# For loop over string ignores characters

Tags: c++, string, loops

So I have simple JSON string that I'm iterating through with a for loop (don't ask why I'm not using a json parser).
In this loop I want to kick out `{`, `}` and ''
(the misplaced `}` is just there for debugging reasons)
Here is the code:

```
std::string str("{'pi': 3.141, 'happy': }true }");
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    char temp = str[i];
    if (temp == '{' || temp == '}' || temp == ' ' )
        str.erase(i, 1);
}
```

Not very complicated and it basically works just fine but for some reason the `}` gets skipped. It just iterates through the string like it wouldn't even be there. Can anyone reproduce this behavior? I'm totally out of ideas what could be wrong here.

EDIT:
Ok, I can see how this might be a duplicate of the other post but to be fair it's hard to stumble upon a post about vectors when having problems with a string

Comment: You can only use a for loop if the number of characters in the string stays the same. But you are removing characters while iterating over the string.

Comment: when some charecter is removed from string, the size of string is changed, and the index positioning not just next element of current( removed) element, but next to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It iterates through the string as if the brace weren't even there, because each closing brace is preceded by a space. Take a simpler example:

```
abc }def
```

The loop reaches `i=3`, the space, deletes it, then proceeds to `i=4`, which is now the 'd'.

You can fix this by decrementing `i` when you erase a character.

Comment: Oh my... I actually thought about the fact that making the string shorter in the process might cause problems but as it worked for all the other characters I assumed it works fine. Of course I had to put my testing symbol after a space as well...